# Change ComboBox Enabled State based on the in another ComboBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two ComboBoxs 1st with `CmdGuarantor` and the 2nd with `CmdGuarantorClass` as names.
`CmdGuarantor` has a list of 7 items:

`NSSF Private MOH Army IS GS UNHCR` while `CmdGuranatorClass` has `1st Class 2nd Class 3rd Class` in its items list.

I want to disable `CmdGuarantorClass` whenever `CmdGuarator.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Private" || CmdGuarator.SelectedItem.ToString() == "UNCHR"`

how can I accomplish that?

P.S.: I tried using the EnableChanged event on `CmdGuarantorClass` ComboBox using this method

> ```
>     private void ComboBox2_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (CmdGuarantor.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Private" || CmdGuarantor.SelectedItem.ToString() == "UNCHR")
>         {
>             CmdGuarantorClass.Enabled = false;
>         }
>         else CmdGuarantorClass.Enabled = true;
>     }
> ```

but with no luck.

thank you in advance.

Comment: I am somewhat confused in relation to the `datagridview` tag and the posted `ComboBox2_EnabledChanged` event. Is your question in reference to two REGULAR `ComboBoxes` or two `ComboBoxColumns` in a `DataGridView` as they are two different things and it is not clear which one you are talking about. Please [edit] your question and clarify this and as already noted what platform you are using... winforms, wpf...? The `datagridview` tag implies a winforms application.

Comment: Dear @JohnG my question is clear, how can i disable CmbGuarantorClass whenever the user selects UNHCR or Private from CmdGuarantor. I am using windows application form as for the datagridview, i am not covering it in this question.

Comment: _" I am using windows application form as for the datagridview, i am not covering it in this question._" .... Then why did you put a `datagridview` tag to this question?

Comment: Thanks for gettings this to my attention, i will remove the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be listening for the [SelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged?view=net-5.0) event, not the EnabledChanged event. EnabledChanged is only raised when the `Enabled` property is changed.

Comment: I do not have the `SelectionChanged` Event on the Event menu for my ComboBOx, where shall I find it?

Comment: Are you using WinForms? Xamarin? WPF? You've not specified so I assumed you were using WPF.

Comment: using WinForms here, It worked I used the `SelectedValueChanged` Event. it did the trick and i believe that the `SelectedIndexChanged` event would do the trick too!

Comment: You're right. If you're more interested in the index than the value object you would use `SelectedIndexChanged` instead. In your case you're more interested in the value than the index. Glad it worked out! :)

Comment: True, it's all about what makes your brain comfy when it comes to values or indexes. any thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `datagridview` tag is a mistake and you are talking about two different `winform` `ComboBoxes`… then… I suggest you wire up the first combo boxes `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

This event will fire when the user changes the selection in the combo box. In that event you can check the combo box values as you have done and then set the other combo boxes `Enabled` property as needed. Something like…

```
private void comboGuarantor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (comboGuarantor.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Private" ||
      comboGuarantor.SelectedItem.ToString() == "UNCHR") {
    comboGuarantorClass.SelectedIndex = -1;
    comboGuarantorClass.Enabled = false;
  }
  else {
    comboGuarantorClass.Enabled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: mistake tag will remove it, thanks

Comment: the datagridview tag is a mistake but your answer in irrelevant